# Type cast from "const char[N]" to custom class in cpp

Tags: c++, linux, casting, uwp

I'm stuck with a c-style cast when compiling a cross-platform code, the problem appears when I compile for UWP, but it works when I remote-compile from Visual Studio to a Raspberry running Linux.

I just want to be able to write this (simplified to minimal problem reproduction):

```
MyClass str = (MyClass) "A beautiful const char[27]";
```

The compiler throw me this error when running for UWP :

```
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'const char [27]' to 'MyClass' 
note: Conversion requires a constructor or user-defined-conversion operator, which can't be used by const_cast or reinterpret_cast
```

I don't understand what is missing in "MyClass", moreover it works on Linux.

Here is an extract of MyClass definition :

```
class MyClass{

    public:

        template<size_t N>
        inline MyClass(const char(&s)[N]) { } //I do something in real life ;-)
}
```

How can I do to make the compiler find a good conversion solution ?

*Edit after some research :*

As I stated in my comment the problem has finally no links to

```
template<size_t N>
inline MyClass(const char(&s)[N]){}
```

This constructor works as is, my problem is located deeper in UWP code and I'll write another question because it is too far from this original question and title.

Thanks a lot again for your help

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/61ubkB).

Comment: Maybe perform an intermediate cast to `void*` or possible `char[1]`. I know some versions of Clang needed an intermediate `void*` cast to avoid warnings for unaligned SSE2 loads.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with any of the compilers [here](https://godbolt.org/g/uUirL3)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - It looks like you are using the wrong compiler and/or flags. You should probably use the MSVC compiler (version 17 or 18 or higher); and not the Clang one. UWP needs a few options and a developer prompt, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @jww I [couldn't reproduce](http://rextester.com/YYQRE65531) while using MSVC as well.

Comment: Thanks @AlgirdasPreidžius. Please forgive my ignorance. What version of the compiler is `vc++`, and what options are used to compile the file? I'm pretty sure options have to include `/DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP` for UWP, which means the Windows 10 SDK should be available. (I was not able to find a setting to display them on http://rextester.com).

Comment: @jww Did you check [about section](http://rextester.com/main)? It clearly states that the compiler being used is: "_Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86_" Hence, it is higher than your suggested version 17, or 18. In addition, I fail to see how operator resolution within a compiler is related to what SDKs are used.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: *"Did you check about section?"* - No I did not check it, thanks. I'm not familiar with the site. *"I fail to see how operator resolution within a compiler is related to what SDKs are used"* - Well, OP is experiencing a problem with UWP and you are not. Maybe it does make a difference.

Comment: Thanks to your help I tried some different reflexion axis and I figured out why the problem appeared on UWP and not on Linux. It's because it's not only due to the code I gave in my post, I realized that the errors appeared due to another constructor that I didn't mentioned : `inline MyClass(Platform::String^ s){ }` and that is obviously excluded from linux compilation. Is it better that I edit my question or I write an answer with the new elements ?

Comment: Please add an answer to close your thread since you already resolved current one and open a new.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Yes I did add an answer but somebody deleted it, I don't know how to do the things in the right way now.